# How do you pass an unordered_map as a function parameter within C++?

Tags: c++

My program was originally set up to pass an array through a function. I have since changed it over to an unordered_map. How can I pass an unordered_map through a function as opposed to something like:

```
int function(int array[])
```

Comment: `int function(const std::unordered_map<T, U>& map)`? I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: @DeiDei My bad. I couldn't find anything on the syntax behind it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you confused? Just replace the `int` with something like `unordered_map<int, int>`.

```
int foo(unordered_map<int, int> x)
```

You're going to want to pass it with a const reference if you don't need to modify it.

```
int foo(const unordered_map<int, int> &x)
```

Don't use the const if you want to modify the original object that was used to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference:

```
int function(unordered_map<K, T> &map)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
int function(const std::unordered_map<int, int> &map)
```

Unless you need to modify the map in which case you'd leave off the const.

If it was my program I'd typedef the map:

```
typedef int result_t;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, result_t> memoization_table_t;

result_t function(memoization_table_t &map)
```

I just made stuff up since I don't know what you're actually doing. The typedefs make templated containers easier to use, and they document the code by using descriptive type names.

Comment: *"they document the code by using descriptive type names"* - sometimes, and other times they obfuscate the code by delocalising things and forcing you to search around to find out what you're actually dealing with.  Optimal balances comes with experience.

Comment: +1 to Tony's comment. I am big fan of code readability. You got to find the right balance. typedef'ing too much could lead to unreadable code, even if its your code, especially when you read it after a month or two.